# Ruby on Rails, Ajax not returning data to web page, or not rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have only been learning Rails for 3 months in my spare time so relatively new to it.I am using Rails 5.1, Ruby 2.4.2, Mysql !4.14 on Ubuntu 16.04.

My problem is that my attempts to use Ajax have all failed.  I have read many, many examples, but when I try to use them in my project I get not response back to the web page.  I have confirmed that the controller is getting called and it appears that it should send back the correct data, but I get nothing back to the web page.

I am trying to filter my index page down from a few thousand records to only those within the category that the user selects.  The filter seems to give me the correct data, but does not make it back to the page.

*Items_controller:*

```
 class ItemsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

      def index
        @items = Item.filter(params.slice(:itemtype_id))
        @itemtypes =Itemtype.order(:description)
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { render "index.html.erb" }
          #format.js { render :partial => "items_div.html.erb" }
          format.js {render layout: false}
          format.json {render json: @items}
          format.all {render :partial => "items_div.html.erb"}
        end
      end
      def show
        @item = Item.find(params[:id])
      end

      def new
        @item = Item.new
        @itemtypes = Itemtype.order(:description).all
      end

      # GET /items/1/edit
      def edit
        @item = Item.find(params[:id])
        @itemtypes = Itemtype.order(:description).all
      end

      def create
        @item = Item.new(item_params)
        @itemtypes = Itemtype.order(:description).all
        respond_to do |format|
          if @item.save
            format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @item }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      def update
        @itemtypes = Itemtype.order(:description).all
        @sourcebooks = Sourcebook.order(:description).all
        respond_to do |format|
          if @item.update(item_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @item }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      def destroy
        @item.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to items_url, notice: 'Item was successfully destroyed.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end

      private
        def set_item
          @item = Item.find(params[:id])
        end

        def item_params
          params.fetch(:item, {})
          params.require(:item).permit(:description,
            :itemtype_id,
            :genericdescription,
            :note)
        end
    end
```

*items.index.html.erb:*

## Items

```
<div itemtype>
  <%= form_with url: items_path(:itemtype), method: :get, remote: true do     |form| %>
  <%= form.label :itemtype, 'Item Type' %>
  <%= form.collection_select(:itemtype_id, @itemtypes, :id, :description,     {:include_blank => 'All'}) %>
  <% # link_to 'List', items_path(:itemtype_id) %>
  <%= form.submit "Go" %>
</div>
<%end %>
<div id="items_div">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @items.each do |item| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to item.description , item%></td>
        <td><%= item.genericdescription %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_item_path(item) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', item, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<br>

<%= link_to 'New Item', new_item_path %>
```

`Items/Index.js.erb`

```
$("#items_div").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'items/items_div'), locals:{items: @items}) %>");
```

*Items._items_div.html.erb*

```
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="3"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <% @items.each do |item| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= link_to item.description , item%></td>
            <td><%= item.genericdescription %></td>
            <td><%= '*' if item.note? %>
            <% if session[:campaignadmin]==true || session[:campaigndm]==true || session[:admin]=='1'%>
            <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_item_path(item) %></td>
            <% end %>
            <% if session[:campaignadmin]==true  || session[:admin]=='1'%>
            <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', item, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
            <% end %>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

*Routes.rb:*

```
  resources :items do
    collection do
      get :itemtype
    end
  end
```

I realize the _item_div is not DRY as it duplicates my main loop, and I will replace the main loop in the index with a render partial once I have things working.

Any help on what I am doing wrong or missing will be greatly appreciated.  I've spent 3 evenings and a weekend working on this and cannot figure out where the disconnect is.

Comment: You need to use partial of items in main index.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

So far as guess you are rendering local variables `items` with your partial so you should not use `@items` at your partial:-

```
#$("#items_div").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'items/items_div'), locals:{items: @items}) %>");
$("#items_div").html("<%=j render partial: 'items/items_div', locals: {items: @items} %>");
```

and in your partial: - Items._items_div.html.erb

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <%# @items.each do |item| %>
    <% items.each do |item| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to item.description , item%></td>
        <td><%= item.genericdescription %></td>
        <td><%= '*' if item.note? %>
        <% if session[:campaignadmin]==true || session[:campaigndm]==true || session[:admin]=='1'%>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_item_path(item) %></td>
        <% end %>
        <% if session[:campaignadmin]==true  || session[:admin]=='1'%>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', item, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Also at your index.html.erb page you should use this partial even , instead of writing same code again like this: - (DRY concept )

```
<div itemtype>
  <%= form_with url: items_path(:itemtype), method: :get, remote: true do     |form| %>
  <%= form.label :itemtype, 'Item Type' %>
  <%= form.collection_select(:itemtype_id, @itemtypes, :id, :description,     {:include_blank => 'All'}) %>
  <% # link_to 'List', items_path(:itemtype_id) %>
  <%= form.submit "Go" %>
</div>
<%end %>
<div id="items_div">
  <%=render partial: 'items/items_div', locals:{items: @items})%>
</div>
<br>

<%= link_to 'New Item', new_item_path %>
```

at your controller: -

```
def index
    @items = Item.filter(params.slice(:itemtype_id))
    @itemtypes = Itemtype.order(:description)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { @items }
      format.js {@items}
      format.json {render json: @items}
    end
end
```

Comment: I have modified the index.html.erb like this:<div id="items_div">
<%= render :partial => "items_div.html.erb"%>

</div>  and it works for the main page but I still see no change to the page when using the form at the top.  If I change the partial to items instead of @items I get Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 336ms (ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)


  
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `items' for #<#<Class:0x00007fbe2ab6fd88>:0x00007fbe29a8d880>

Comment: I don't actually see the page changing at all when I click Go.  I would expect either a blank partial, or an error somewhere.

Comment: The server appears to be rendering it, but the page does not actually change.  I see this on  the server:Processing by ItemsController#index as 
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "itemtype_id"=>"2", "commit"=>"Go"}
  Item Load (3.5ms)  SELECT `items`.* FROM `items` WHERE `items`.`itemtype_id` = 2
  Rendered items/_items_div.html.erb (64.2ms)

Comment: @KeithWoolston-Young could you check the latest code as i modified the index action , lets don't use respond_to block as rails itself smart enough to differentiate js and html request.

Comment: My guess would be something wrong with the javascript that should replace the <div> but I'm not sure what could be wrong with it.  The server seems to be doing what it should and I get no errors there.

Comment: I am not sure what you are suggesting I do.  When I changed the _items_div.html.erb from @items to items, I get the  "ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `items' for"  error message.

Comment: @KeithWoolston-Young sory i did not notice the code but i noticed just now here is mistake, kindly replace in js,erb like this: - `$("#items_div").html("<%=j render partial: 'items/items_div', locals: {items: @items} %>");`

Comment: @KeithWoolston-Young its a typo with your `(render partial: 'items/items_div'), locals:{items: @items})`, i means not correct syntax. as i modified the answer, hope is should work now. :)

Comment: @KeithWoolston-Young incase you are getting same error you can use respond_to block as well. also change `index.js.erb` code, and let me know for further guidance.

Comment: I still see no change on my page.  The server says it is rendering it, but the page does not respond to any changes.  Also thank you for taking the time to help me with this.

Comment: I was getting an "unknown format" error without the format.all in my controller.  Could that be causing issues?

Comment: @KeithWoolston-Young could you check at browser console is there any javascript error ? or could you use pry or debugger at js.erb or at partial whether its rendering `@items ` after ajax request?

Comment: @KeithWoolston-Young not sure, in that case you can use `render layout: false` with `respond_to` block.

Comment: Browser console is clean. index.js.erb now reads like this:   debugger;
$("#items_div").html("<%=j render partial: 'items/items_div', locals: {items: @items} %>");  This does not appear to stop here.

Comment: seems your it does not respond @items after your ajax request, can you use debugger at controller whether its getting js request and after submitting form or whether its getting any request at your action?

Comment: So my server has "Processing by ItemsController#index as HTML" when I load the page but "Processing by ItemsController#index as " when I use the button that should be an AJAX call.  I'm wondering if this is my whole problem.

Comment: binding.pry stops in the controller, but I'm not sure how to determine what format has been passed in.

Comment: @KeithWoolston-Young if its ajax request you will see at server console like this: - `Processing by ItemsController#index as JS`. or you can also check like this: - at your controller `request.xhr?` it will return 0 or 1.

Comment: I think this is my problem.  request.xhr? responds with 0.  Server shows "Processing by ItemsController#index as " with no JS after.  Somehow the request is getting there, but not as a javascript request.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I solved it!  thank yo so very much for your help with this.  My problem was in the form_with url: items_path(:itemtype).  It should not have the (:itemtype) as that was changing the format in the controller to format="itemtype".

Comment: @KeithWoolston-Young i guessed so before, but i had no idea of form_with, anyway sounds good, feel free to upvote answer if it helped you :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue now.  Thanks for all the help, as it all contributed to my understanding of the issue.

The solution came down to 2 issues.

1) the form_with call had url: items_path(:itemtype)... and should have simply been url: items_path...  this caused the respond_to in the controller to not recognize the format (it was seeing itemtype as the format instead of JS)

2) the index.js.erb was changed to:

```
$("#items_div").html("<%=j render partial: 'items/items_div', locals: {items: @items} %>");
```

Items.controller.index now reads as follows and was the only method changed in here

```
def index
    if params[:itemtype_id]!=nil and params[:itemtype_id]!=0
      @items = Item.filter(params.slice(:itemtype_id)).order(:description)
    else
      @items = Item.order(:description)
    end
    @itemtypes =Itemtype.order(:description)
     respond_to do |format|
       format.html { render "index.html.erb" }
       format.js {render layout: false}
      end
end
```

This is simpler and now works as intended.

Thank-you again for those who spent their time in helping me figure this out.